# openjpa: illegal argument exception for value object

Tags: constructor, openjpa, named-query

there is a NamedQuery like this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "getOpakOdeslaniForPartner", query = "select
```

new com.vo.OpakOdeslaniVO(opak.pocetPokusu, opak.idSekvenceOpakovani.idOpakSekvence, opak.idSekvenceOpakovani.sekvence) 
   from  GmOpakOdeslani opak, GmPrijemce prij 
   where opak.idTypZpravy.idTypZpravy = :typZpravy and opak.idPrijemce = prij and prij.idPrijemceTyp.idPrijemceTyp = :typPrijemce"

The value object has single constructor with three parameters.

There is a such log (WebLogic 11g, HP-UX):

```
Caused by: <openjpa-1.1.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1172209 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.util.UserException: There was an error packing the projection and/or aggregate results of the query into result type "class com..vo.OpakOdeslaniVO".  See the nested Throwable exception for details.
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultPacker.packUserType(ResultPacker.java:262)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultPacker.pack(ResultPacker.java:225)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.QueryImpl$PackingResultObjectProvider.getResultObject(QueryImpl.java:1960)
    at com..service.OpakOdeslani.getOpakOdeslaniForPartner(.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1516.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor747.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ResultPacker.packUserType(ResultPacker.java:235) ... 114 more
```

Actually I feel stuck, as there is no explanation message for IllegalArgumentException and I cannot find a source code for GeneratedConstructorAccessor747 class. Any idea, what is going on and how to fix this issue? I guess there must be some problem with the value object constructor or class.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the types for `opak.pocetPokusu, opak.idSekvenceOpakovani.idOpakSekvence, opak.idSekvenceOpakovani.sekvence` are the sames types as provided by the constructor of com.vo.OpakOdeslaniVO.

As a debug point you could just select those fields to ensure that data is being returned?

Comment: I realized, that types match: OpakOdeslaniVO(int pocetPokusu, long opakSekvence, String sekvence). But when I go to SQL, there is no data returned by the query. So why do JPA call the constructor when query returns no row?

Comment: opak.idSekvenceOpakovani.idOpakSekvence - opak has no rows, table returned by idSekvenceOpakovani has two rows. But I assume that if a master table has no data, then a detail table cannot be matched, can it? It is strange behaviour, because 1) it started to fail once somebody inserted a row into the detail table 2) it runs OK on another environment where there are rows in both master and detail tables. The source code is same for two years.

Comment: It sounds like someone might have messed up when they inserted some data?

Comment: I might explained tables relationship incorrectly. Let simplify it: table A (id_sequence int, sequence_definition varchar), table B (counter int, id_sequence int), where B.id_sequence is foreign key to A. There is a row in table A but no row in B, so join SQL query will return nothing. But equivalent JQL throws constructor error: select new VO(b.counter, b.sequence.sequenceId, b.sequence.sequenceDefinition) from BEntity b. Thank you for any hint